# To what extent do the conditional components determine the probability distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Given three random variables , $X \in \mathbb R$ (a real number) , $Y\in \{0, 1\}$ , and $Z\in\{0, 1\}$ ,
let $(X\mid Y=0, Z=0)\sim\mathcal N(\mu_0, 1)$ and $(X\mid Y=0, Z=1) \sim\mathcal N(\mu_1, 1)$ ,

What can we say about the distribution of $X\mid Y=0$?

Comment: You have a probability equal to a distribution, what does that mean? Also, how can $X$ be discrete and draw probabilities out of a normal distribution?

Comment: Nice Catch about "Discrete X" : It was my typo while I was editing. It should be "real number" ! Your other Catch , @SotArmen , about "Probability = Distribution" , It is notation Issue : I will let OP respond & rectify that.

Comment: I've edited the notation to address the second concern

Comment: [ +1 ] Though there are other notations available , your Current Notation is somewhat Common !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can not say much about $P(X\mid Y=0)$ without knowing the Probability of $Z$.
We have to use this formula , where we currently have 2 "unknowns" multiplying the 2 "knowns" :

$$P(X\mid Y=0)=P(X\mid Y=0, Z=0)P(Z=0)+\\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ P(X\mid Y=0, Z=1)P(Z=1)$$

When $P(Z=0)$ is almost $0$ , then that term will "vanish" & the other term will "Dominate".
When $P(Z=0)$ is almost $1$ , then that term will "Dominate" & the other term will "vanish".
Other-wise , Both terms will Contribute.

Even when we want to get Probability of $X$ , we will have 4 "unknowns" :

$$P(X)=P(X\mid Y=0, Z=0)P(Y=0)P(Z=0)+\\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ P(X\mid Y=0, Z=1)P(Y=0)P(Z=1)+\\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ P(X\mid Y=1, Z=0)P(Y=1)P(Z=0)+\\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ P(X\mid Y=1, Z=1)P(Y=1)P(Z=1)$$

When we know these "Multipliers" , of course , it is easy to get what we want , though that is a Different Question.

Comment: thank you. that clarifies it.